# How to exclude a package from codenarc?

Tags: groovy, gradle, codenarc

I am new to Gradle and Codenarc but I found no example showing how to exclude a package from codenarc reports.

For example, I have a groovy application that uses, for instance, the package myapp.main and myapp.legacy

I want all my ruleset applied to myapp.main but none to myapp.legacy.
How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of places where to look for such information:

1. The [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html), which has a chapter for each plugin.
2. The [Gradle Build Language Reference](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/index.html) (specifically the `CodeNarc` task type).
3. The samples in the full Gradle distribution.
4. The [Gradle forums](http://forums.gradle.org).

According to 2., an `include` or `exclude` filter should do the trick. For example:

```
codenarcMain {
    exclude "myapp/legacy/**"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answer seems to be a little bit old. For codenarc documentation itself it is best to refer to its [website](https://codenarc.org/).

As explained [there](https://codenarc.org/codenarc-configuring-rules.html#applying-rules-based-on-class-name-andor-package-name) you can include or exclude files, packages or classes from rules by specifying every rules' properties in the config file. An example is bellow:

```
CatchThrowable.doNotApplyToClassNames=BaseController,AbstractTest

FieldName.applyToClassNames=org.codenarc.CodeNarc,org.codenarc.extra.*
```